# VIM: EOF error when python code requires input

Tags: python, vim

I did setup Vim on my OS X machine, but when I try to execute a code

```
x=input("which one you like? ")
print(x)
```

I get an error:

[image]

I should mention that there was similar thread, but no acceptable solution was suggested except for not writing any interactive programs..

I will post my .vimrc file content, maybe it can help:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
"git interface
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
"filesystem
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim' 

"html
Plugin 'isnowfy/python-vim-instant-markdown'
Plugin 'jtratner/vim-flavored-markdown'
Plugin 'suan/vim-instant-markdown'
Plugin 'nelstrom/vim-markdown-preview'
"python sytax checker
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/Pydiction'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'

"auto-completion stuff
"Plugin 'klen/python-mode'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'klen/rope-vim'
"Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
""code folding
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'

"Colors!!!
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'

call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on    " enables filetype detection
let g:SimpylFold_docstring_preview = 1

"autocomplete
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1

"custom keys
let mapleader=" "
map <leader>g  :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>
"
call togglebg#map("<F5>")
"colorscheme zenburn
"set guifont=Monaco:h14

let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc$', '\~$'] "ignore files in NERDTree

"I don't like swap files
set noswapfile

"turn on numbering
set nu

"python with virtualenv support
py << EOF
import os.path
import sys
import vim
if 'VIRTUA_ENV' in os.environ:
  project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
  sys.path.insert(0, project_base_dir)
  activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir,'bin/activate_this.py')
  execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
EOF

"it would be nice to set tag files by the active virtualenv here
":set tags=~/mytags "tags for ctags and taglist
"omnicomplete
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete

"------------Start Python PEP 8 stuff----------------
" Number of spaces that a pre-existing tab is equal to.
au BufRead,BufNewFile *py,*pyw,*.c,*.h set tabstop=4

"spaces for indents
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*pyw set shiftwidth=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw set expandtab
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set softtabstop=4

" Use the below highlight group when displaying bad whitespace is desired.
highlight BadWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red

" Display tabs at the beginning of a line in Python mode as bad.
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw match BadWhitespace /^\t\+/
" Make trailing whitespace be flagged as bad.
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/

" Wrap text after a certain number of characters
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw, set textwidth=100

" Use UNIX (\n) line endings.
au BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h set fileformat=unix

" Set the default file encoding to UTF-8:
set encoding=utf-8

" For full syntax highlighting:
let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on

" Keep indentation level from previous line:
autocmd FileType python set autoindent

" make backspaces more powerfull
set backspace=indent,eol,start


"Folding based on indentation:
autocmd FileType python set foldmethod=indent
"use space to open folds
nnoremap <space> za 
"----------Stop python PEP 8 stuff--------------

Pauliuss-MacBook-Pro:~ Paulius$ less .vimrc

" Use UNIX (\n) line endings.
au BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h set fileformat=unix

" Set the default file encoding to UTF-8:
set encoding=utf-8

" For full syntax highlighting:
let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on

" Keep indentation level from previous line:
autocmd FileType python set autoindent

" make backspaces more powerfull
set backspace=indent,eol,start


"Folding based on indentation:
autocmd FileType python set foldmethod=indent
"use space to open folds
nnoremap <space> za
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `:w !python`, the standard input is a temporary file or pipe with your code, which `python` naturally reads to the end in order to execute the script, hence it's EOF when it gets to `input()`, and input is not from a terminal.
To solve this problem, insert a line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line of your code file, save it, do `:!chmod +x %` once and then execute it with `:!%`.